# Upgrading Xamarin Forms to .Net MAUI app.config

Tags: maui

I am working on migrating xamarin forms application to .net maui.

As part of migration i am working on using reviewing the packages. I amusing PCL App.Config Manager for get setting out of a App.config file. Do I still need this ?

https://github.com/mrbrl/PCLAppConfig

Comment: Do you mean something like preferences: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/preferences?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=android

Comment: I have never heard of this, can you link it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the [Portable Class Libraries (PCLs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/pcl?tabs=macos) are considered deprecated in the latest versions of Visual Studio. While you can still open, edit, and compile PCLs, for new projects it is recommended to use .NET Standard libraries to access a larger API surface area. It's important to review the packages and libraries you're using to ensure they are compatible with .NET MAUI or to find alternatives that provide similar functionality.

In .NET MAUI, the approach to configuration and settings management has evolved. .NET MAUI uses a more modern approach to application settings, often leveraging built-in features such as `Preferences` for storing simple key-value pairs, or `Configuration` for more complex settings which can be loaded from various sources like JSON files, environment variables, secure storage, etc. You can check this link about [the Preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/preferences?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=android) in MAUI.

Here are some suggestions:

1. **Preferences**: For simple settings, you can use the `Preferences` class provided by the `Microsoft.Maui.Storage` namespace. This allows you to store and retrieve key-value pairs and is a direct replacement for similar functionality in Xamarin.Forms.
2. **Configuration**: For more complex settings, you can use the `Configuration` API provided by the `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` namespace. This allows you to load settings from various sources, including JSON files, which can be a replacement for the traditional App.config files.
3. **Compatibility Check**: If the PCL App.Config Manager package is not compatible with .NET MAUI, you will need to find an alternative or update the code to use the aforementioned APIs.